# How do you alphabetically sort a two column table using raw javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, sorting, html-table

Say I have the following table:

```
<table border="1">
    <tr class="row">
        <td>mammal</td><td>dog</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
        <td>fish</td><td>goldfish</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
        <td>plant</td><td>bush</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
        <td>plant</td><td>tree</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
        <td>mammal</td><td>cat</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
        <td>fish</td><td>shark</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I'm trying to sort this table alphabetically.  I want to first sort it by the first column, then, sort the second column on a 'per category' basis.  So the end result I'm looking for is:

```
fish    |  goldfish

fish    |  shark

mammal  |  cat

mammal  |  dog

plant   |  bush

plant   |  tree
```

How do I go about performing this two dimensional sort using Javascript?  My initial idea is to create an array of rows (clones, not the actual elements), and then sort those, delete the innerHTML of the table, and then one by one inject the clones in sorted order.

I'm struggling with the actual sorting algorithm, and which well-known algorithm would be best to use for the two columns and how to properly implement it in Javascript.

Comment: Frankly, I would start with the data in an object and build the table dynamically from that object. Then an alphabetic sort is simple and you just rebuild the table with the newly sorted data.

Comment: You should have your data in an array, and use the `sort` method that all arrays have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming table id is myTable, this will reorder and display the table.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function sortRows(a,b)
    {
        return a.first > b.first || (a.first == b.first && a.second > b.second);
    }
    var table = document.getElementById('myTable');
    var rows = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++)
    {
        rows.push({ 'first': table.rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML, 'second': table.rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML });
    }
    var sortedRows = rows.sort(sortRows);
    for(var i = 0; i < sortedRows.length; i++)
    {
        table.rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML = sortedRows[i].first;
        table.rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML = sortedRows[i].second;
    }
</script>
```

I've used innerHTML, though it could be innerText instead.

Answer (score -1):

first you need to assign an **ID** to your table then try the codes below (for example, I used **mytable** as **ID** on this sample)

```
var table = document.getElementById("mytable");
var firstArray = new Array();
for (var i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
    firstArray.push(table.rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML + "-" + table.rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML);
}
// now perform a basic sort
for (var i = 0; i < firstArray.length; i++) {
    for (var ii = i + 1; ii < firstArray.length; ii++) {
        if (firstArray[i] > firstArray[ii]) {
            var tmp = firstArray[i];
            firstArray[i] = firstArray[ii];
            firstArray[ii] = tmp;
        }
    }
}
// display results
for (var i = 0; i < firstArray.length; i++) {
    console.log(firstArray[i]);
}
```

then you can loop on the array if you want to split it into two arrays